# NGXS Continuous Triggered Effects

Tags: rxjs, ngxs

Im trying to create a sample perhaps we switch to NGXS from angular redux + redux-observable.

We do have several usages which starts running based on an action and stop when something else happens running, which I'm not 100% sure how they should be handled. Small scenario:

on connect => listen to heroChanges

on disconnect => unsubscribe

```js
    @Action(HeroRealtimeActions.Connect)
    heroChanged(ctx: StateContext<HeroRealtimeStateModel>) {
        return this.hubClient.heroChanged$().pipe(
            // tap(x => console.warn(">>>> hero changed", x)),
            mergeMap(heroes => ctx.dispatch(new HeroActions.Update(hero))),
        );
    }
```

This is how i want it to work:

- `Connect` completes and not block it e.g. returning Observable it will not complete (as above)
- `takeUntil` on `disconnect`
- cancel/ignore if `connect` is triggered again e.g. ala `switchMap`

The above works good however I dont want to block the Connect.

In redux-observable we use to have something as following:

```js
action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(HeroRealtimeActions.connectSuccess),
    switchMap(hubConnection => this.hubClient.heroChanged$().pipe(
        // do something...
        takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(HeroRealtimeActions.disconnectSuccess))),
        ignoreElements(),
    ))
);
```

Another option I was thinking is using manually `.subscribe()` use `actions$` to `takeUntil`, but will need something else for `switchMap` - but it sounds it will get a bit messy

I can easily get something half baked working, I'm more asking for a correct way of doing it

Comment: Seems like what you have for the connect action, would be a dispatched action that never completes: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle. What happens if that action is dispatched again? You could solve that by using a cancellation, but then why is it an action in the first place? It just seems to me like it would be a generally better approach to use some mechanism outside of an action to connect. I'm not sure what your hubs are doing or for, but observables seem like a "hub" to me anyways. Seems like your hubs should just be raw observables.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport hubs are SignalR connections (websockets), but they are essentially simply an observable in js terms. So what I want in this case is update the state with the new changes that I'm subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the most equivalent and also quite clean is to use the `ActionHandlers` as described here https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers. Changed the above as following:

```js
actions$.pipe(
    ofActionSuccessful(HeroRealtimeActions.Connect),
    switchMap(() => this.hubClient.heroChanged$().pipe(
        // tap(x => console.warn(">>>> hero changed", x)),
        mergeMap(hero => store.dispatch(new HeroActions.Update(hero))),
        takeUntil(actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(HeroRealtimeActions.Disconnect))),
    )),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Yes this is what I do with something like FireBase. Anytime a websocket/push based system is being used, I open a listener outside of the actions and have the socket dispatch the appropriate action.